# How can I simulate a network delay when unit testing an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, mocking, jasmine

I am using the `$httpBackend` service in module ngMock to simulate a GET request.  From the [AngularJS documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend), here is an example controller:

```
// The controller code
function MyController($scope, $http) {
  var authToken;

  $http.get('/auth.py').success(function(data, status, headers) {
    authToken = headers('A-Token');
    $scope.user = data;
  });

  $scope.saveMessage = function(message) {
    var headers = { 'Authorization': authToken };
    $scope.status = 'Saving...';

  $http.post('/add-msg.py', message, { headers: headers } ).success(function(response) {
    $scope.status = '';
  }).error(function() {
    $scope.status = 'ERROR!';
  });
  };
}
```

and, here is the corresponding Jasmine test spec:

```
// testing controller
describe('MyController', function() {
  var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController;

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
   // Set up the mock http service responses
   $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
   // backend definition common for all tests
   $httpBackend.when('GET', '/auth.py').respond({userId: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});

   // Get hold of a scope (i.e. the root scope)
   $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
   // The $controller service is used to create instances of controllers
   var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');

   createController = function() {
     return $controller('MyController', {'$scope' : $rootScope });
   };
 }));


 afterEach(function() {
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
 });


 it('should fetch authentication token', function() {
   $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth.py');
   var controller = createController();
   $httpBackend.flush();
 });


 it('should send msg to server', function() {
   var controller = createController();
   $httpBackend.flush();

   // now you don’t care about the authentication, but
   // the controller will still send the request and
   // $httpBackend will respond without you having to
   // specify the expectation and response for this request

   $httpBackend.expectPOST('/add-msg.py', 'message content').respond(201, '');
   $rootScope.saveMessage('message content');
   expect($rootScope.status).toBe('Saving...');
   $httpBackend.flush();
   expect($rootScope.status).toBe('');
 });

 it('should send auth header', function() {
   var controller = createController();
   $httpBackend.flush();

   $httpBackend.expectPOST('/add-msg.py', undefined, function(headers) {
     // check if the header was send, if it wasn't the expectation won't
     // match the request and the test will fail
     return headers['Authorization'] == 'xxx';
   }).respond(201, '');

   $rootScope.saveMessage('whatever');
     $httpBackend.flush();
   });
 });
```

As written above, the mock request responds instantly when executing the tests.  I would like to set a delay on the mock GET request.  Is this possible?  I have a feeling the [`$timeout`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout) service will be needed to achieve this.

**Bonus Question:** Are there any drawbacks to setting a delay like this?  Is this a reasonable thing to do in an AngularJS unit test?

Comment: about the bonus question: http://superuser.com/questions/330501/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-or-limit-the-bandwidth-that-firefox-can-us I don't think this is something you want to have in a unit test

Comment: @EduardGamonal: I don't literally want to throttle a browser; angular's `window.setTimeout` counterpart should be sufficient.

Comment: yes, you can use timeout, but you should be testing two things: small bandwidth and high latency. you can do that with iprelay + firefox throttle. I think that unit tests are to test input/output of components, not how reliable the application is on harsh network conditions.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now.

Answer (score 2):

Create a decorator for $httpBackend, like this one: http://endlessindirection.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/angularjs-delay-response-from-httpbackend/

Put this in your app.js, for a 700ms delay during each mocked or passthrough response:

```
.config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function($delegate) {
        var proxy = function(method, url, data, callback, headers) {
            var interceptor = function() {
                var _this = this,
                    _arguments = arguments;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callback.apply(_this, _arguments);
                }, 700);
            };
            return $delegate.call(this, method, url, data, interceptor, headers);
        };
        for(var key in $delegate) {
            proxy[key] = $delegate[key];
        }
        return proxy;
    });
})
```

Bonus Answer: I believe time is not something you would test in an unit test. But for sure you need to test for server errors, that's why mocked http comes handy.

And I use delay like this when prototyping, that's a valid scenario too.